# WCF Service Deployment in IIS Page cannot be displayed and how does the SVC file work?

Tags: wcf, iis, deployment, service

Arghhh! I'm getting so frustrated trying to get my head around this WCF service.

So I created a WCF service. It works fine in my laptop where I launch it from Visual Studio 2010. Now I have to deploy it on a Windows Server 2003 machine. So I created a virtual directory on that server's IIS. Next I copied the WCF Service DLL file in the virtual directory. I also created an SVC file which had the following entry:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="AMWCF.Service1" %>
```

**Ok first of all, I'm so confused here. Where does this line tell the Server where the DLL file is? It just says "AMWCF.Service"! not file location!**

So when I try to launch my webpage, it gives an error "THE PAGE CANNOT BE DISPLAYED". I've tried everything which I can find on the net including:

1. Reinstalling the ServiceModelReg
2. Restrarting IIS
3. Allowing ASP.NET in IIS

Sorry for showing my frustration here. I really really reallllly appreciate any help. Thanks guys. You guys are the best

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? If using VS2010, then you can use the Publish command to publish the service properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a class library with your WCF service inside, you need to copy the service DLL into the `.\bin` folder **one level down** from your virtual directory. That's where the WCF runtime looks for its service classes.

Also see these resources:

- MSDN docs: [How to: Host a WCF Service in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx)
- endpoint.tv Screencast - [Hosting WCF Services in IIS](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Hosting-WCF-Services-in-IIS/)

The [WCF Developer Center on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF) has a "Beginnger's Guide" (available right from the landing page) which has **tons** of those excellent 5-10 minute screencasts explaining all things WCF to you - highly recommended!

Comment: Screencasts aren't very helpful when your IT department blocks all streaming video. I wish Microsoft realized that.

Answer (score 2):

Page cannot be displayed error is coming from IIS.

- Add a simple html file and see if IIS can serve that file
- Add a simple aspx file and see if IIS can serve that file
- Now add .svc file as one of the documents in document list in IIS
- Place dll in a bin folder under the virtual directory's physical path
- Once you get the asp.net run time errors, it is easy find the answers
  for them

Answer (score 1):

If this stuff is new to you, you should use the visual studio deployment features, try right click your web project and click deploy, I think it'll solve your issues, you can even deploy using ftp through this wizard.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. I can't use Visual Studio cause the Server that I'm working on does not have it. Any work aorund it?