# How does the .SVC file in WCF Service work?

Tags: wcf, iis, dll, service, svc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WCF Service Deployment in IIS Page cannot be displayed and how does the SVC file work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051640/wcf-service-deployment-in-iis-page-cannot-be-displayed-and-how-does-the-svc-file)

A Typical WCF SVC file will have the following;

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="AMWCF.Service1" %>
```

The SVC file informs nothing on the location of the WCF Service dll file.

So when someone opens this SVC file link in HTTP (provided the Service is hosted in IIS), how does the link know where to get the dll file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks for the class in an assembly in the \Bin directory.